# Eclipse Plugin - Hide tags

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tags, hide

I override Eclipse Text Editor. I want to hide tags.

For example, 
in document file:

```
< color>Context< /color>
```

show user:

Context

and show context's color is red.

I can do red but I couldn't hide tags.

How can i do that?

Comment: You would probably have to use your own `IDocumentProvider` and `IDocument` to leave the tags out of the document text.

Comment: Can you give me an example?